# ngValue is ignored when used inside ng-content in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, controlvalueaccessor

I have created a custom control say **my-select-input** in Angular that wraps native select input. Template looks like this.

```
<div class="select-container">
<select
    class="form-control"
    [ngModel]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="value$.next($event)">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </select>
</div>
```

**my-select-input** component looks like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.value$ = new BehaviorSubject(this._value);
    this.valueSubscription = this.value$.subscribe((value) => {
      this._value = value;
      this.onChangeCallback(this._value);
    });
  }
```

Component also extends a class that implements controlvalueaccessor.

When I try to use the component like this :

```
<my-select-input formControlName="select">
      <option *ngFor="let item of selectValues" [ngValue]="item">{{item.label}}</option>
</my-select-input>
```

ngValue is completely ignored and the value I get is the text between the options tag. I use ngValue to store an object inside it. Not sure what is the problem here. Any help is appreciated.

Control works perfectly fine with value attribute instead of ngValue.

Similar issue - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22374

Comment: That's kind of the point of `ng-content`: The projected content does not run in the context of the component. Otherwise `*ngFor="let item of selectValues"` wouldn't work. You cannot have both.

Comment: @abetteroliver Than you for pointing in right direction.